# Microsoft Word 2010 Style Sets - Where to get downloads

Tags: microsoft-office

Knowing that I can edit existing styles, is there anywhere that offers style-sets that can be downloaded and added to the list of available style-sets that come with Microsoft Office 2010?

Another way to put it is that I would like to expand on the available Style-Sets without having to create or edit them myself. I know how to do those things, but I am not good at making them eye pleasing; so I want to have broader range of ones that are already designed.

Answer (score 0):

You may go to the Blue Menu, go to the document templates, and then go to some place that says "Get More Themes". I believe you can search, and it'll get more templates.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/templates-partners-FX010242583.aspx

Comment: Thank you Adam, but there was no option for themes or style sets, only for templates. What I'm looking for pertains to "Style Sets" AKA "Quick Style Sets" found under the "Change Styles, Style Set" option on the "Home" Tab of the ribbon in Office 2010. There is a predefined set of styles there and I would like to expand it without having to edit or create them myself.

Comment: Style Sets are wrapped up with Themes and not easily extricated.